# Windows NFS Performance vs Windows File Sharing?

Tags: samba, nfs, windows

Has anyone set up NFS where both the server and the clients are all Windows?  I am wondering:

- How Does Performance Compare to using builtin Windows file sharing (CIFS/SMB)?
- Can clients mount NFS shares as network drives just like with regular file sharing?
- Any recommended tools since Windows does not support this natively?
- Does doing this provide reliable file sharing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CIFS/SMB really should be your choice for Windows clients & servers - NFS can be very insecure without the hassle of Kerberos.  Using SMB you get the standard Windows security model.

- Performance wise there is not not much much in it - possibly SMB is a bit faster.
- XP needs Windows Services for UNIX ([here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=896c9688-601b-44f1-81a4-02878ff11778&displaylang=en)) to mount NFS
- Windows Server can only mount NFS shares not offer them.  It has to use SMB.
- Reliability for an XP client mounting an NFS share from a Linux server so far has been fine, although we only have a couple of machines doing this.

In conclusion for a Windows server, NFS is not an option.  For an XP client only use NFS if you have to - due to only having a Linux server when you don't want the hassle of setting up SAMBA

Comment: NFS is much lighter and much faster than SMB. This is the old question though but at that time NFS were faster anyways.

Comment: Windows Server can provide a NFS share to other OSes, but the performance on a Linux client is very bad.

Comment: What's the case now in 2019?

Answer (score 0):

I tried using NFS using a Synology (linux) to Windows clients and the performance was beyond abysmal.  Returned to using SMB.